# XAML Windows 8 AppStore not scrolling

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, scroll

I'm pretty new to XAML and Windows 8 app development and got a problem regarding scrolling.

I have a details page where under the standard "Back arrow" and Page Title there is something like a Table where it should show a key in my case the string "METAR" and left to it a value which is also a string but pretty long.

So I did this with a Grid and and Textblocks.

My problem is: When the value String(Which is pretty long) exceeds the visible part of the display it just gets cut off... I cant scroll to see the rest of it.
I Although tried to put a scrollviewer around the part I wanted to scroll but the result was me beeing able to pull the cut of text in the left an right direction but not scrolling so far.

I'm afraid I have a blunder in my Layout overall with width values, I tried everything I could think of and compared my xaml to the ione from thr grid-template but I couldn't find out why my APP isn't Scrolling to the right when my Textblock exceeds the displaylimit :/

Thanks for any help and here is my XAML

```
<Page
    x:Name="pageRoot"
    x:Class="firstBlankApp.DetailPage"
    DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:firstBlankApp"
    xmlns:common="using:firstBlankApp.Common"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <!-- TODO: Delete this line if the key AppName is declared in App.xaml -->

    </Page.Resources>

    <!--
        This grid acts as a root panel for the page that defines two rows:
        * Row 0 contains the back button and page title
        * Row 1 contains the rest of the page layout
    -->
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Back button and page title -->
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="backButton" Margin="39,59,39,0" Command="{Binding NavigationHelper.GoBackCommand, ElementName=pageRoot}"
                        Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        AutomationProperties.Name="Back"
                        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="BackButton"
                        AutomationProperties.ItemType="Navigation Button"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Text="{Binding Airport.Name, FallbackValue='Airport Name'}" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" Grid.Column="1" 
                        IsHitTestVisible="false" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,30,40"/>
        </Grid>

        <!-- Content Grid with Metar and content-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="250" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Margin="20,0,0,0" Text="METAR" FontSize="40"></TextBlock>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock x:Name="TbMetar" Margin="1,1,1,1" Text="{Binding Weather, FallbackValue='Loading metar...'}" FontSize="40" TextWrapping="NoWrap" ></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    </Page>
```

With Scrollviewer:

```
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="250" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Margin="20,0,0,0" Text="METAR" FontSize="40"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" x:Name="TbMetar" Margin="1,1,1,1" Text="{Binding Weather, FallbackValue='Loading metar...'}" FontSize="40" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Height="auto"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: For starters, where's your `ScrollViewer`?

Comment: I've put the scrollviewer version below. But the grid template can scroll without a scrollviewer, so I thought I don't really need it.

Comment: OK, I got it working myself... 
 
VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"                                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"

was missing... But still I dont understand why the Grid-Template works without a sscrollviewer... is it because of the GridVIEW? is that a superpower of the gridview to scroll automatically?

Comment: Yes, [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709916.aspx) has a `ScrollViewer` already built into its `Style` template. I didn't see a `GridView` anywhere in your example though.

Comment: No this project doesnt have a Gridview, I had a Gridview in the grid-template where I look and try to understand how the result was achieved, didnt know that the gridview had a scrollviewer integrated, thanks for the hint :)